Shell Theory 1 for electrostatic doubts about excess charge on the surface of the shell?
So I am using David Halliday Fundamentals of Physics book, and I have come accross shells theorem in chapter 21 page 615. I am confused when excess charge is removed from a spherical shell the excess charge being negative, is then replaced by positive charges? I do not get how this process works.
